# Use Phone NFC Chip to emulate Mifare card

Tags: android, nfc, mifare

I know, there has been a few ppl asking this question but that was around the Time when Andriod 4.4 was still around. I found something in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11471952/nfc-used-as-mifare-is-it-possible) Thread but im not sure if anything has changed since then.

Comment: You didn't ask any question

Answer (score 2):

Nothing in Android has changed, it's still not possible to emulate a non standard Mifare card unless the firmware of a specific chipset has the feature and you can hack it to enable it.

It's probably got even worse as there are more chipset suppliers for NFC in Android now and most of these don't even support reading Mifare cards never mind emulating them.

The only thing that might have made it better is more support for USB on the Go, which would allow you to use a NXP external USB reader that has Mifare emulation capabilities (no hacking needed for this)