# Emulate NXP - Mifare Classic 1k

Tags: java, android, flutter, nfc, rfid

**my RFID reader Info:**

**Protocol**        : ISO1443A

**Frequency**       : 13,56MHz

**Voltage**         : 7-12V ile 3,3-5V

**Flow**            : 60-100mA

**Supported Cards** : S50, S70, Ultralight, Desfire, Mifare, Mifare Plus, Mifare Pro

**Working card Info:**

**Tag Type**: ISO 14443-3A

NXP- Mifare Classic 1k

**Technologies avaliable**: NfcA, MifareClassic, Ndef

**Question** is this: It is possiable to Emulate this card with NFC mobile devices on RFID reader ?

Not: When I Tap My phone on RFID reader the reader is show 01020304 value on screen its reading actualy but how can send diffrend data like cardID.

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Use Phone NFC Chip to emulate Mifare card](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70187048/use-phone-nfc-chip-to-emulate-mifare-card)

Comment: Actualy the reader can read my phone when NFC is enable I got 01020304 and some id. but I dont know how to send diffrent data or id.

the phone which I use for test is LG V20

Comment: Kindly note that Stackoverflow is not a free code writing service. The question "how to read from and write to a Mifare classic card" is not so unusual here on SO to find a lot of places to start with.

Comment: @Enes Reading the NfcA UID that is randomly generated by the phone is common to many different tag technologies, the phone can emulate a Type 4 Tag with an HCE service but other then the very low level UID that is totally different to how a Mifare Classic behaves.

Comment: @MichaelFehr I don't need from you any free code I just need information who experience NFC&RFID cominication.